# jta with spring in web application

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, jta

If I follow [spring and bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Spring+Framework) instructions and I run web application on tomcat, do I still need to configure:

1. in web.xml the resource-ref
2. in context.xml the resrouce and transaction tag
3. in web.xml the bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener
4. in resource.properies the Data resource?

I prefer to configure the bitronix (btm) only in spring and not in tomcat. is it possible in web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions ought to be associated with the service tier, which does not depend at all on the web tier.  (The web tier, however, does use the service tier to fulfill requests.)

If that's the case, there shouldn't be a reason to embed information about transactions in any configuration except Spring's.

Comment: thanks. can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027539/bitronix-spring-hibernate-persistence I saw that you answered but I can't figure out the problem. You wrote to use tomcat JNDi and I don't want to. I have 100 reputation as well:) to give

Comment: Your error says: "Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource: jdbc/testDS1".  That's a JNDI lookup name.  So where does "I don't want to" fit into this?  Spring needs a Java Naming and Directory service to look up the data source associated with this name; that's what Tomcat provides.  If not Tomcat, where do you propose that Spring get it from?  The naming service is part of the Java EE app server.

Comment: This problem was solved. My problem is that it doesn't find the java:comp/UserTransaction that if I use tomcat I have to use in resource